# Retrieve previous versions of Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I saved over a version of a form I was creating.

Is there any way to retrieve the original?

Is there a version archive?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

No, I'm sorry to say that we do not have version archive or history of a Cognito Form. This is a feature that we can pass on to our developers.